# how to differentiate between already created and new objects in the template while using model formset

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I am not quite sure about if i am taking the right approach to accomplish this. What i want is to (change the css for) / (use some jQuery methods on) the form elements rendered by the modelformset that have pre-filled data. For example i have the following modelformset.

```
    EduFormSet = modelformset_factory(models.CandidateDegree,
                 form=forms.CandidateDegreeForm)
    edu_formset = EduFormSet(prefix='candidate_degree',
                  queryset=models.CandidateDegree.objects\
                           .filter(candidate=can))
```

when i pass this `formset` to the `template` it renders forms for all the existing `CandidateDegree` objects with the pre-filled data and a blank form as well.

What i am trying to achieve is not to show the pre-filled forms but just the data for the objects that are already created and append an edit button to the element (using jQuery) which would then show the form. And at the end of the object list show the blank form generated by formset.

i am aware that i could pass all the `CandidateDegree` objects related to a `Candidate` as a seperate dictionary to show the information. but in that case how do i append the form to the formset so that the dynamically generated forms become the part of the formset and all the information is saved when a user clicks on a submit button.

what would be the best approach to achieve something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to show the complete form, you can loop over the formset like this:

```
 {% for form in edu_formset %}
      form.FIELDNAME#1.value
      form.FIELDNAME#2.value
      etc.
 {% endfor %}

 <!-- Manually render empty form for new entry -->
 <div class='input'>
     <label>Locality: </label> <input id="FIELDNAME#1" disabled=disabled value="">
     <label>Country:  </label> <input id="FIELDNAME#2" disabled=disabled value="">
     etc.
 </div>
```

So you're only showing the database values of all objects send to the template, not the form inputs.

Then indeed with minimal jquery (or plain javascript) you can show/hide the div.input